# Setting onerror handler on popup

Tags: javascript, error-handling, popup

I would like to pass a callback into a function that displays a popup (I've made it an iframe in example for convenience). However, I can't get `window.onerror` to work when setting it from the reference to the newly open window. What am I doing wrong? (Tested in Chrome)

The embedded script runner didn't work, so here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/PWSDF/35/

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">New Window</button>
<button id="btn2">New Window 2</button>
<iframe name="popme"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Works
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var win = window.open('', 'popme');
    var doc = win.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<scr" + "ipt>window.onerror = function() { alert(1); return true}</scr" + "ipt>" +
        "<scr" + "ipt>badCall1()</scr" + "ipt>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>Nothing really</body>" +
        "</html>"

    );
    doc.close();
});
// Doesn't work
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var win = window.open('', 'popme');
    var doc = win.document;
    win.onerror = function () {
        alert(1);
        return true;
    }
    doc.open();
    doc.write(
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<scr" + "ipt>badCall2()</scr" + "ipt>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>Nothing really 2</body>" +
        "</html>");
    doc.close()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching the **onerror** handler after the Document has been opened seems to work. However, I'm not sure why it works this way.

JSBin (tested only in Chrome): http://jsbin.com/seveniqubi/1/edit?html,js,output

```
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var win = window.open('', 'popme');
  var doc = win.document;

  doc.open();

  win.onerror = function(message, url, line) {
    alert(message);
    return true;
  };

  doc.write(
    "<html>"+"<head>" +
    "<scr" + "ipt>badCall2()</scr" + "ipt>" +"</head>" +
    "<body>Nothing really 2</body>" + "</html>");

  doc.close();                                                             
});
```

Comment: Dang, I can't believe I didn't try that.

Comment: I just got lucky though. I was formatting code and for no logical reason I formatted it like that... and voila! It worked.